# How to call an async function from the main thread without waiting for the function to finish (utilizing aioconsole)?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

**I'm trying to call an async function containing an await function from the main thread without halting computation in the main thread.**

I've looked into similar questions employing a variety of solutions two of which I have demonstrated below, however, none of which seem to work with my current setup involving `aioconsole` and `asyncio`.

Here is a simplified version of what I currently have implemented:

```py
import aioconsole
import asyncio

async def async_input():
    line = await aioconsole.ainput(">>> ")
    print("You typed: " + line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(async_input())

    print("This text should print instantly. It should not wait for you to type something in the console.")
    while True:
        # Do stuff here
        pass
```

> I have also tried replacing `asyncio.run(async_input())` with the code
> below but that hangs the program even after entering console input.
>
> ```py
> loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
> asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
> loop.create_task(async_input())
> loop.run_forever()
> ```

What's currently happening:

1. Function is created ✓
2. Function is called from the main thread ✓
3. The program stops and awaits the completion of the async function. ✗
4. The processing that should be performed in parallel with the async function is performed sequentially. ✗

Output

```
>>>
```

**What should happen:**

1. Function is created ✓
2. Function is called from the main thread ✓
3. The program continues while the async function runs in the background. ✓
4. The processing following is performed in parallel with the async function. ✓

Expected output

```
>>>
This text should print instantly. It should not wait for you to type something in the console.
```

Python version: 3.10.8 
Operating System: MacOS Ventura

Comment: I think you're missing one of the key concepts of asyncio. In asyncio, you are not using threads, everything still happens one at a time. What it can do is weave in calls together by deferring actions that are being awaited on. The call to `asyncio.run` is blocking, it will not continue until all of the async logic from the co-routine issued has completed. If you need true concurrency, use threads or multiprocessing. In this case, I would make an async main method which calls `async_input` as a task, performs its work, and then awaits `async_input` before finally returning.

Comment: In addition to what @flakes is saying, threads don't run in parallel either in Python. If you want true paralellism, you need `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Yep, "true parallelism" is what I should have said. Concurrency being to allow multiple actions to happen concurrently by taking turns (which is what threads and asyncio in python provide in different ways), vs parallelism which allows the actions to actually be performed at the same time (typically achieved with multiprocessing).

Comment: I see! So in my case, I should start a separate thread and run the function congruently in that thread. Multiprocessing seems a little overkill given the lack of processing performed by my function. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The `while True: pass` is what is really killing usage here. Because it does not await anything it will never allow other co-routines to take a turn executing. What you would really want is have a main that awaits something to allow other tasks to take a turn. `while True: await asyncio.sleep(1)` would allow this,

Comment: See the official docs. They are very informative and practical https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: I read the docs prior to posting, but I think I understand it now. I didn't realize asyncio.run was a blocking function, I need downtime so the function can run and my main content should really be in an async function. I've adapted my code and it works now! I'll post an answer so others in the future can learn from my mistake.

Comment: Nice! Glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out to me by @flakes there were a couple of problems with my approach:

1. `asyncio.run` is a blocking function so wrapping my async function calls in it was preventing any following code from running.
2. The main content needs to be wrapped in an asynchronous function to give the indented async function time to run.
3. The intended async function runs while the main thread is waiting so downtime must be introduced in the main function. This can be easily done with `await asyncio.sleep(x)`.

The introduction of all this fixes the problem while allowing the main content to run synchronously:

```
import aioconsole
import asyncio

async def async_input():
    line = await aioconsole.ainput(">>> ")
    print("You typed: " + line)

async def main():
    input_task = asyncio.create_task(async_input())

    print("This text should print instantly. It should not wait for you to type something in the console.")
    while True:
        # Do stuff here
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    
     await input_task
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Note that you should also store the response of `asyncio.create_task(async_input())` to a variable and await on it before the main function completes. This ensures proper ordering of the lifetime for your coroutines. Using an `asyncio.TaskGroup` would help handle that as well in a more terse setup.

Answer (score 2):

`asyncio.run()` starts and manages an asynchronous event loop and waits until all *async* job is done. If you need to run some synchronous code concurrently with async coroutines/tasks you need to "embed" that code into the event loop, in particular with [`asyncio.to_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread) function:

```
import aioconsole
import asyncio
import time

async def async_input():
    line = await aioconsole.ainput(">>> ")
    print("You typed: " + line)

def func():
    print("This text should print instantly. It should not wait for you to type something in the console.")
    time.sleep(5)
    print('other stuff ...')

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(asyncio.to_thread(func), async_input())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

---

```
This text should print instantly. It should not wait for you to type something in the console.
>>> some text
You typed: some text
other stuff ...
```

---

> **Note:** Due to the GIL, `asyncio.to_thread()` can typically only be used to make IO-bound functions non-blocking. However, for extension
> modules that release the GIL or alternative Python implementations
> that don’t have one, `asyncio.to_thread()` can also be used for
> CPU-bound functions.

The alternative is to use [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor).
To apply it the `main` function needs to be changed to the following:

```
async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    await asyncio.gather(loop.run_in_executor(None, func), async_input())
```

Comment: +1 Might also be nice to add some disclosure to the usage of `asyncio.to_thread` as this can be easily abused and introduce some noticeable slowdowns to code which could otherwise be purely aio based.

Comment: @flakes, ok, added some info/notes/alternatives